# Name for an electrical element to use multiple appliances on the same plug

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, image-identification

Sorry, I don't know what is this element called in English. It is an electric power cord with multiple sockets to allow multiple appliances to be plugged into it. In Spanish it is said to be informally a “*zapatilla*”, but in English?

[image: Socket Strip]

or

[image: Extension Lead]

Comment: I thought zapatilla was shoe?  Why are power strips called that?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. I don't know why -.-

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This varies country to country, even internally within English speaking countries.

In the UK, in shops they usually refer to it as a "multi-way extension lead".  Also referred to as a "socket strip", "socketboard", "power strip", "extension socket", "extension cable", "plug board".

Probably a few other things.

Comment: They're called 'power-boards' in Australia.

Comment: Power bars in Canada.

Comment: I'd say "plug board" is the most common term in the UK.

Comment: lived in the UK until I was 25, never heard the phrase "plug board" (or "socketboard", for that matter")!  I've always called it a "4-gang [power] extension", or "2-gang..." etc. depending on the number of sockets.

Comment: @simon: Yes, I've heard 4-gang and 2-gang plenty, forgot about those.  "plugboard" and "socketboard" I tend to hear more from builders and electricians, perhaps newer terms.

Comment: I've not heard "plug board" in the UK, "(six-way)(mains) extension lead" seems the most common term to me. Perhaps there are strong regional variations. To me a plug board is what was used in early telephone exchanges. A "power bar" here would be a snack aimed at people striving to be athletes.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: I think the consensus is that there is no firm consensus. ;-)

Comment: I invoke ... [the oracle!](http://www.maplin.co.uk/power/mains-electrical/extension-leads)  (I just know this will end in tears - be gentle)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: See! They sort of agree with my primary answer, except I used the word "multi-" as the generic term for whatever *n-way* extension socket they are selling. ;-)

Comment: @ghoppe "Power bar" is common in the UK as well.

Comment: It is quite astonishing, Amazon UK responds correctly to all the names mentioned here!

Answer (score 13):

The items in the pictures are commonly known as *[power strips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_strip)*. Some power strips also have the ability to prevent [power spikes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_spike), and those can also be called *[surge protectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surge_protector)*.

Answer (score 6):

*Power bar* is another common term. (At least in Canada.)

Comment: I, for one, have never heard them called that (in my part of the US, at least).  I think of some kind of energy bar (food) when I hear "power bar."

Comment: @advs89 it's true the energy bar has usurped the phrase. However, up here in the Great White North, *power bar* is not an uncommon term. :) http://www.canadiantire.ca/AST/browse/7/Electronics/TVsAccessories/ElectricalPowerBars.jsp?locale=en

Comment: I have to admit, "power bar" sounds much cooler.

Answer (score 3):

That would be a "Power Board" in Australia.

Comment: That sounds like some kind of hyped up surfing mechanism... (good to know, though)

Answer (score 0):

We call them multi-plugs in South Africa

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

That would be called as an **Extension Board** in India.

An [example](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Extension+Boards&i=home-improvement&crid=1W361VUBGUBR3&sprefix=extension+board%2Chome-improvement%2C528&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) of use on Amazon India.

Comment: Can you provide some examples that show this term is used in India? (Links to websites selling some would be good.)

Comment: [link] (https://www.amazon.in/s?k=Extension+Boards&i=home-improvement&crid=1W361VUBGUBR3&sprefix=extension+board%2Chome-improvement%2C528&ref=nb_sb_noss_1)